# Minimum Spanning Tree time complexity

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

I have this MST implementation for Prim Algo which is |V| to the power 3 . But the CLRS says it says the complexity is O (E * lg |V| ) assuming |V| ~ |E| its O(|V| * lg |V|) . My implementation may be fixed but i am not sure how can we go below |V| * |V| with a matrix implementation

```
class matrix_graph
{
private:
    int** v;
    int vertexes;
public:
    matrix_graph(int**, int);
    ~matrix_graph(void);
    bool is_connected(int i,int j);
    int egde_weight(int i,int j){return v[i][j];}
};






int mst()
{
    int v[9][9] = {  
        {0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,8},
        {0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,11},
        {0,8,0,7,0,4,0,2,0},
        {0,0,7,0,9,14,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,9,0,10,0,0,0},
        {0,0,4,14,10,0,2,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,2,0,6,1},
        {0,0,2,0,0,0,6,0,7},
        {8,11,0,0,0,0,1,7,0}
    };

    int* ptr_v[9];
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        ptr_v[i] = & v[i][0];
    }
    matrix_graph* m = new matrix_graph(ptr_v , 9 );

    std::set<int> tree;
    tree.insert(0);

        std::set<int> non_tree;
        non_tree.insert(1);
    non_tree.insert(2);
    non_tree.insert(3);
    non_tree.insert(4);
    non_tree.insert(5);
    non_tree.insert(6);
    non_tree.insert(7);
    non_tree.insert(8);

    int i = 0;
    int min = _I32_MAX;
    int add_to_tree;
    int sum = 0;

    while(!non_tree.empty()){
        for(std::set<int>::iterator iter = tree.begin() ; iter != tree.end() ; iter++ ){
            for(std::set<int>::iterator iter_n = non_tree.begin() ; iter_n != non_tree.end() ; iter_n++){
                int edge = m->egde_weight(*iter , *iter_n);
                if( edge > 0 && edge < min)
                {
                    min = edge;
                    add_to_tree = *iter_n;
                }
            }
        }
        tree.insert(add_to_tree);
        non_tree.erase(add_to_tree);
        sum += min;
        min = _I32_MAX;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to maintain a list of edges, not just an adjacency matrix, to maintain a |V| log |v| running time. That way you can find all edges and sort faster - [Kruskal's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm).

Comment: You can also try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm (Prim's Algorithm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to representing the graph using Adjacency list (not Adjacency Matrix). Then your implementation can give O(E * lg |V| ).

If you further want to optimize the running time you can use Fibonacci heap to extract minimum. Then you can achieve  O (|E| + V * lg |V| ) running time. Using Fibonacci heap you can find and delete an element in amortized O(lg n) running.

More details:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap

Fibonacci heap was also discussed in CLRS Book.